# How to reduce the CPU load on a hosting with WordPress installed as a CMS?

Tags: wordpress, cpu

I have been using hostgators hatchling plan for three months. I got an email from the hosting that my website is creating an over load on CPU. They said that I am eating up their processor and as a precaution, they have temporarily suspended my account.

When I contacted their customer support, they said:

> You have to optimize your database and use some sort of caching
>   mechanism, where the script does not need to generate a new page with
>   every request, helps to lower the over load that a script will cause.

I am not a technical geek, I am wondering how I will do this thing. I don't have any resource to hire a web developer to do this job. My website is down for 48hours. I was using wp super cache along with cloudfare's free support.

Now I have intalled optimize-db plugin and optimized my database. Please provide me with some more tips on how to optimize my database to reduce CPU usage. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about 'optimising a database' or finding a web host that allows more resources. For Database Optimisation in WordPress you should use the Stack Exchange WordPress site > http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=optimize+database for finding a website host please see our catch all > http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements Shared hosting you are limited in resources, even a optmised database can go over that limit. Feel free to continue this in our chat channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost I'd suggest changing hosting to a hosting company that can actually handle a wordpress install without you having to change things like this.

Yes you can optimise your wordpress with some of the things you have already mentioned, but why go with a host who can't even cope with what they advertise there plans as, wordpress hosting.

You don't need to be paying any more than you are either. Looking at the plan you are on, its slightly more expensive than the plan I use to host a Wordpress site install and I've never had these issues.

I'd suggest doing a bit more research into hosts, you will be able to find a better host for the same price.

Comment: thank you ... mate, can you please which host you were using ??